# implementing angular-ui-router 'otherwise' state

Tags: angular-ui-router

If a user types **myURL/** or **myURL/#/** or even **myURL/#/foo** they get to my index page.

But if they type **myURL/foo**, they get a 404. This is terrible. They should instead be redirected to **/**.

I am trying to implement this and am not having a lot of luck.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {


            $stateProvider
                .state('index', {
                    name: 'index',
                    url: '/',
                    templateUrl: 'js/views/page1.html',
                    controllerAs: 'page1Controller',
                    data: { pageTitle: 'Main' }
                })
                .state('page2', {
                    name:'page2',
                    url: '/page2/:id',
                    templateUrl: 'js/views/page2.html',
                    controllerAs: 'page2Controller',
                    data: { pageTitle: 'page2' }
                })
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        }]);
})();
```

I have looked at dozens of articles, and nowhere do I seem to be able find this simple case handled.

Answer (score 0):

On the [official docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-routing#urlrouterprovider) it is mentioned that you can pass `$injector` and `$location` to the function otherwise.

Their example looks like this:

```
app.config(function($urlRouterProvider){
    // if the path doesn't match any of the urls you configured
    // otherwise will take care of routing the user to the specified url
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/index');

    // Example of using function rule as param
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location){
        ... some advanced code...
    });
})
```

What you can do to achieve your goal is to create a state, and whenever something it's not matched and enters otherwise fct, send it to that state.

```
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location){
    $injector.get('$state').go('404');
});
```

I have not tested this but should work.

Comment: Is what I'm trying to do not standard behavior for a website? Anytime a user types a bad URL they'll just end up back on the homepage?

Comment: By default, AngularJS will route URLs with a hashtag. Whatever is not after the hashtag is not a valid route in the default angular 1 $locationProvider. This issue can be solved by removing the # (modifying the $locationProvider. It was removed in Angular 2. I hope this helps. If you need help removing the # let me know.